# Stack cannot be resolved to a type - VsCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to simply use a stack in java but, I get this error message

Code:
[image]

Error:
[image]

I tried to run "java clean" in the command palette to no effect. I use the java pack that Microsoft has recommended https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack . My JDK is the Development Kit 8 but I wouldn't think this to be the issue.

Comment: same problem even with java 16.0.2 2021-07-20

Answer (score 2):

To run VS Code for Java, **Java SE 11 or above version** is required. I'm using AdoptOpenJDK11 and the code works well:

[image]

Please install JDK11 or Rencent Version as JDK for language server.

Comment: I got the same issue as well, even though I got java 16 installed